# Let $g\in\scr{S}(\Bbb R^n)$, then $\frac1h\Delta_{h e_j}\to\partial_j g$ in $\scr{S}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $g\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be Schwartz class, and recall that given $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we define the finite difference $\Delta_hf(x)=f(x+h)-f(x)$ for $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore, I wish to show that $$\frac{1}{h}\Delta_{h e_j}g\xrightarrow{h\to0}\partial_j g$$ in $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, or more explicitly, that for all multiindices $\alpha,\beta$, $$x^\beta\partial_x^\alpha\left(\frac{g(x+h e_j)-g(x)}{h}\right)\xrightarrow{h\to0}x^\beta\partial_x^\alpha\partial_j g(x)$$ uniformly. Now, it's not so hard to show that uniform convergence when $\alpha=\beta=0$ implies uniform convergence when $\beta=0$ and for all $\alpha$, but I don't see how to prove either the base case, or a more general induction argument (though I suspect that it's only the base case that's the hard bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g(x+he_j)-g(x)=\int_0^h\partial_jg(x+te_j)\,dt,$ by differentiating under the integral sign you get $$\partial_x^\alpha g(x+he_j)-\partial_x^\alpha g(x)
=\int_0^h\partial_x^\alpha\partial_jg(x+te_j)\,dt.$$
Hence, 
$$x^\beta\frac{\partial_x^\alpha g(x+he_j)-\partial_x^\alpha g(x)}{h}-x^\beta\partial_x^\alpha\partial_jg(x)=\frac1{h}\int_0^h[x^\beta\partial_x^\alpha\partial_jg(x+te_j)-x^\beta\partial_x^\alpha\partial_jg(x)]\,dt.$$
Now you can use the fact that $x^\beta\partial_x^\alpha\partial_jg(x+te_j)\to x^\beta\partial_x^\alpha\partial_jg(x)$ as $h\to 0$ uniformly in $t$.